# Auto-increment child line item for each given parent ID

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I do not know the correct jargon for this topic so here goes.  I have a SQL table built like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MANUAL_LINE_ITEMS]
  ( [SHIPMENT_ID] [int] NOT NULL
  , [LINE_ITEM_ID] [int] NOT NULL
  , [JOB_NUMBER] [nvarchar](50) NULL
  , [RELEASE_NUMBER] [nvarchar](50) NULL
  , [NO_OF_PCS] [nvarchar](50) NULL
  , [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](100) NULL
  , [SSMA_TimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT PK_MANUAL_LINE_ITEMS_SHIPMENT_ID_LINE_ITEM_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SHIPMENT_ID],[LINE_ITEM_ID])
   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I would like the LINE_ITEM_ID to auto-increment for each SHIPMENT_ID and then reset for the next one.  My SHIPMENTS table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SHIPMENTS]
  ( [SHIPMENT_ID] [int] identity(1,1) NOT NULL
  , [JOB] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
  , [REL] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
  , [SHIPMENT_NUMBER] [int] NOT NULL
  , [DATE] [datetime2](0) NULL
  , [FREIGHTCHARGE] [smallmoney] NULL
  , [SHIPPER] [nvarchar](50) NULL
  , [MANUAL_LINE_ITEM_ENTRY] [bit] NULL
  , ...
  , CONSTRAINT PK_SHIPMENTS_SHIPMENT_ID_JOB_REL_SHIPMENT_NUMBER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SHIPMENT_ID],[JOB],[REL],[SHIPMENT_NUMBER])
   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

An Access form for SHIPMENTS uses a subform to add/list line item details.  I have the ability to re-work the SQL tables if necessary or use Access VBA events.  What needs to be done to get the LINE_ITEM_ID to auto-increment for each SHIPMENT_ID?  TIA.

Comment: You want to generate a custom unique identifier. This is a common topic. Requires VBA to calculate and save to table. Otherwise, let a report calculate this line item number by using RunningSum property of textbox and report Grouping feature.

Comment: Thanks June7.  This is needed to make the records unique among themselves and written to its SQL table.  So I will need to make the subform unbound and write SQL UPDATE statements in VBA to write each record or set of records, correct?  And that means I'll have to plan/write VBA to CRUD?

Comment: Subform does not need to be unbound. Need VBA in some event such as form BeforeUpdate to calculate value and populate field.